# Delphi OpenDialog for FTP server

Tags: delphi, ftp, opendialog

Is there a way to use opendialog or savedialog to navigate on FTP server? 
I've tried to use 
`InitialDir := 'ftp://ftpip'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A description how an FTP server can be integrated with Explorer without any third-party tools can be found at

[CyberNotes: Map a FTP to a Drive in Windows](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/)

> The solution I’m about to show you doesn’t exactly assign a drive
>   letter to the FTP server, but it will essentially serve the same
>   purpose as a drive. Through Windows Explorer you’ll have one-click
>   access to your files, and they will even be accessible through the
>   standard Open/Save dialog boxes in apps such as Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shell extension (within your project, but in a separate DLL) which will create a virtual folder from your remote FTP server. Then your open/save dialogs will be able to navigate to this virtual folder and choose files there.